# How to get type of template of class from its object in C++

Tags: c++

I have a custom class A and want to get the type of template from the code which initialized an object of A class to use it as a variable later. Is that possible?

```
#include <functional>

template<class T>
class A {
public:
    A(){};
    T data;
};

int main() {
    A<int> a;

    // How to get int as type?
    // function <void (type)> foo;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Review `value_type` in the GCC std::array definition: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/array

Comment: Cheapest and easiest I can think of: `std::function <void (decltype(a.data))> foo;`. This has the advantage of only needing `a`, but the disadvantage of needing to know about a member of `A` (and obviously will not work if that member is `private`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you would like the template type to be discoverable by code, you can make a public `using` to expose it:

```
template<class T>
class A {
public:
    using type = T;  // <<<< add this (or something like it)

    A(){};
    T data;
};
```

Then in main

```
int main() { // side note: main() *must* return an int
    using AI = A<int>;
    AI a;
   
    function <void (AI::type)> foo;
}
```

*[Edited to match your question that changed after this was posted.]*

Comment: I have updated my question. About solution: Ye, I think that's it! Could you update your answer to be more correct? And I heard that it's possible to do that using `typedef`s, isn't it?

Comment: @OwlCodR updated to match your changed question.  `typedef` is superseded by `using`, but both will work here.

Comment: @ChrisUzdavinis, ok thanks for help!